# How to Save a Node

Tags: java, save, binary-tree

I've been coding a basic binary Tree in Java and have run into a problem. The goal of this program is to "learn" new questions in order to guess an animal similar to 20 questions. However, I have no idea how to "save" a node so it can be recalled by this same class the next time it runs. How to do this?

```
public class LearningTree {
Node root;

public void addNode(double key, String name){
    Node newNode = new Node(key, name);
    
    if (root == null){
        root = newNode;
    } else {
        Node focusNode = root;
        
        Node parent;
        
        while(true){
            parent = focusNode;`enter code here`
            
            if(key < focusNode.key){
                focusNode = focusNode.leftChild;
                
                if(focusNode == null){
                    parent.leftChild = newNode;
                    return;
                }
            } else {
                focusNode = focusNode.rightChild;
                
                if(focusNode == null){
                    parent.rightChild = newNode;
                    return;
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
}
 public void traverse(Node focusNode){
 if(focusNode != null){
     
     traverse(focusNode.leftChild);
     
     traverse(focusNode.rightChild);
 }
 }


 class Node{
 
 double key;
 String name;
 
 Node leftChild;
 Node rightChild;
 
 Node(double key, String name){
     this.key = key;
     this.name = name;
 }

}

public void keyChange(Node focusNode, double newkey){
focusNode.key = newkey;
 }

public Node findNode(double key) {
     
 

 Node focusNode = root;

    while (focusNode.key != key) {


      if (key < focusNode.key) {

          focusNode = focusNode.leftChild;
     
          } else {
 
              focusNode = focusNode.rightChild;
          }

          if (focusNode == null)
                return null;

}

   return focusNode;
     
}
 

 public static void main(String[] args){
 LearningTree Tree = new LearningTree();
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
 
 //Nodes
 Tree.addNode(1500, "Does it have wings?");
 Tree.addNode(750, "Is it a dog?");
 
 
 
 System.out.println("Is it an animal?");
 
 double n = 1000;
 
 while(true){
 String Answer = sc.nextLine();
 String answer = Answer.toLowerCase();
 
 double k = n;
 

 if(answer.equals("y")){
     n = 1.5* n;
 }
 if(answer.equals("n")){
     n = .5*n;
 }
 if(Tree.findNode(n) != null){
 
 System.out.println(Tree.findNode(n).name + " (y/n)");
 }
 
 if(Tree.findNode(n) == null){
     System.out.println("What is it?");
     String answer1 = sc.nextLine();
     System.out.println("What would distinguish a " + answer1 + "from the     previous guess?");
     String answer2 = sc.nextLine();
     System.out.println("What would the answer be to " + answer2 + "? (y/n)");
     String answer3 = sc.nextLine();
     double s;
     
     if(Tree.findNode(k/1.5) == null){
         Tree.findNode(k/.5);
     } else {
         Tree.findNode(k/1.5);
     }
     
     if(answer3.equals("y")){
         Tree.keyChange(Tree.findNode(k), n );
         s = 1.5;
         Tree.addNode(n, Tree.findNode(n).name);
     }
         
     if(answer3.equals("n")){
             Tree.keyChange(Tree.findNode(k), n);
             s = .5;
             Tree.addNode(n, Tree.findNode(n).name );
     }
     Tree.addNode(k, answer2);
            
    
        
         
             

            }
        
         
     }
     
     
     
     
     
 }

 
 
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could use a local file and serialize the data. Java handles this pretty well.

NOTE: I haven't tested this code but it's a starting place.

```
private void saveNode(Node n){
    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("file.txt");
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);
    oos.writeObject(n);
    oos.close();
}

private Node readNode(){
   FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("file.txt");
   ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fin);
   Node n = (Node)ois.readObject();
   ois.close();
   return n;
}
```

Comment: No, apparently its not seriazable or whatever this meansException in thread "main" java.io.NotSerializableException: LearningTree$Node
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
 at LearningTree.saveNode(LearningTree.java:103)
 at LearningTree.main(LearningTree.java:167)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to serialize this object to a file so that it can get the data back when it runs next time through deserialize. Check ObjectOutputstream class's documentation. Having said that you need to have some logic to go with it,